# Instant Clone in vdi horizon

Tags: clone, vdi

i new in vdi horizon and  i am really confused , in vdi horizon instant clone , floating desktops ,

do the instant clones have their own dedicated Memory and CPU resources , or instant clones are going to use the master vm's memory ?

Comment: Any VM hosted on a hypervisor will use the hypervisor's physical memory, CPU, and storage. This is obviously a finite amount of resources.